# GY-80 with Raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, i2c

I followed below link in github and made all tweaks, (i2c working well and sensor gives output for other codes found in internet, but this code has this problem/s)

**[GY-80](https://github.com/peterjc/longsight/blob/master/gy80.py)**

errors come as this,

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26) 

[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART    
>>> 
Starting...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/raspi/i2c-sensors/bitify/python/sensors/gy80.py",    line    202, in <module>
    imu = GY80()
  File "/home/pi/raspi/i2c-sensors/bitify/python/sensors/gy80.py", line 69, in __init__
    bus = smbus.SMBus(i2c_raspberry_pi_bus_number())
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

and specially`bus = smbus.SMBus(i2c_raspberry_pi_bus_number()) IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` error was there as I was calling other support files (*adxl345.py, hmc5883l.py bmp085.py, l3g4200d.py , i2cutils.py and imu.py etc..*) to gy80.py.

can anyone explain how to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the I2C has been disabled by the device tree overlay

See [this](https://github.com/pimoroni/skywriter-hat/issues/4) discussion which appears to be the same as your code.

you can enable the I2C device using the `raspi-config` tool.